Power BI Desktop: Summarization options (percent of grand total) not available for explicit measures in field well
I am using the latest April update of Power BI desktop: Version: 2.128.952.0 64-bit (April 2024)
I have enabled some new preview features including 'Visual calcutations'.
I have a very simple 'Matrix' visual that shows a country and total sales.
Total Sales is a measure I created: Total Sales = SUM('Internet Sales'[Sales Amount])
Total Sales is formatted as a Currency with 2 decimal places.
I'm experimenting and learning DAX and want to add a new column onto my visual that displays the 'Percentage of Grand Total" for each customer.
I know how to do this via other methods (e.g. with a new visual calculation or another measure). But that's not the problem.
The problem is that when I click on the 'Total Sales' value in the field well, I can't see the summarization options.
I am certain that in previous versions of Power BI Desktop, the options such as 'percent of grant total' were there for explicit measures.
Am I missing something (obviously)? Have the options moved?
Couple of things to note:
Relationships exist in the data model and it's not actually my data but data from an online course that I downloaded.
Any input would be greatly appreciated.
Andrew


Why not just create an explicit measure by hand?
DIVIDE ([Measure],
CALCULATE([Measure], ALL(...)), BLANK() )

Yes good point. However, I couldn't understand why the summarization options weren't available. I've now figured it out and realised that I should right-click on the field well and it's ll there. I will post a solution.

It turns out that I should actually be 'right-clicking' on the value in the field well and the summarization options become available.
